# Why is the first value of my char array 10?

Tags: c, char, scanf, newline

I'm new to programming but I wanted to make a program that gets as input a number, (length) and then stores a series of a's and b's of said length. Finally it should output the numbers as the ascii numbers. (so 97 and 98)
I thought I should malloc a char array of the size length and then do a for-loop over it and print everything as an integer.

The problem is however that I get a value 10 as the value of the first letter.
Thanks a lot for any help!

```
int main()
{
    int length;
    scanf("%d", &length);
    char *matrix = malloc((length + 1 ) * sizeof(char));

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
            scanf("%c", &matrix[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
            printf("\n%d", matrix[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When inputting 3 on the first line and aba on the next line, I get 10 97 98.
However I expected it to be 97 98 97. Why do I get a value of 10 in the first place of the array?

Comment: Hint:  hitting the "Enter" key produces a character that has ASCII value of 10.  More generally,  check the value of the character `'\n'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
scanf(" %c", &matrix[i]);
      ^^^^
```

instead of

```
scanf("%c", &matrix[i]);
       ^^
```

When the format starts with a blank all white spaces are skipped.

From the C Standard (7.21.6.2 The fscanf function)

> 5 A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by
>   reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains
>   unread), or until no more characters can be read.

10 is the ASCII code of the (white space) new line character `'\n'` that was present in the input buffer after you entered the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

The first `scanf()` with the format string `%d` leaves a newline in the input buffer.

What happens here, is that your terminal collects input one full line at a time, passing it to the program, and then the `scanf()` only reads the digits from the buffer, leaving the newline character there for the next `scanf()` to see. The same would happen if you entered `10 abc`: the space, `abc` and the newline would be left there.

This mismatch is not something people usually expect, and it's one of the things that makes `scanf()` annoying. I would suggest using `fgets()` instead to first read a full line, matching what the terminal gives, and then parse the number from it with `sscanf()` or `strtol()` (or `atoi()`).

This cleans up the issue at the point where the first line is read, instead of passing it on to the next input function to handle. Otherwise all your input functions are tied together, if the next input would be for a whole line with possible white space, you'd need to know if you expect to clear a pre-existing newline or not. (You could also replace the later `scanf("%c")` with `getchar()`, not that that matters with buffering though.)

That said, the `scanf("%c")`/`getchar()` loop may still see newlines if you enter lines that don't have as many characters as the loop expects, so if you don't want to see them at all, filter them out.

So, something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int length;
    char linebuf[100];
    fgets(linebuf, 100, stdin);
    length = strtol(linebuf, NULL, 10);
    char *matrix = malloc(length + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = getchar();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d", matrix[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

(The obvious downside of `fgets()` is that you have to decide on a maximum length for the input line, allocate a buffer and call another function in addition to it.)